# Unable to push to cocoapods trunk

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

I am trying to publish my cocoa touch framework in cocoapods, first I run the command `pod spec lint` and spec validation passes but when I push my framework to trunk by `pod trunk push [NAME_OF_FRAMEWORK.podspec]`, it gives me following error,

> CocoaPods was not able to update the `master` repo. If this is an
>   unexpected issue and persists you can inspect it running `pod repo update --verbose`.

Comment: Did you try the verbose option to get more information on what went wrong?

Comment: Yes I tried but it also gives the same error message

Comment: Have you successfully authenticated to the pods system?

Comment: yes I have trunk session running in my device.